# How would I make a variable get row data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I'm writing a program and am trying to make a variable get row data.

    `// I'm not going to write all the beginning stuff
     DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
     JTable t = new JTable(model);
     model.addRow(new Object[]{x , y , z});
     String s = null`

So how would I make s be equal to y (I know I could change y to s but I need so you can change y).

Comment: Make your Object array non-anonymous (i.e. declare it so you can refer to it again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply declare your Object array, like so:

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
 JTable t = new JTable(model);
 Object[] myArray = {x, y, z};     // Magic!
 model.addRow(myArray);
 String s = myArray[1];
```

Comment: Thanks this helps so much Ill make it the answer when I can